# Tradinview api: automaticly add users to private Indicator

Tags: trading, indicator, tradingview-api

I was wondering if Tradingview offers an API call to manage users and give rights to private indicator scripts? I would like to publish an Indicator as "invite-only": I would like to setup a Link on my Website, where users can add there Username, and these users will get access to the Indicator.

Is this at all possible? Does Trading view offer this? Is there maybe a hacky solution?

Cheers!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is unofficial but did you check this one?

https://rapidapi.com/financetrading/api/tradingview-rest

I am using this for a long time and I will use it until TradingView published their own API.

Comment: Can you provide me an example use-case I am working on a similar thing